# Best practice null, false or ??? if no matching row is found when pulling an object from a DB?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm building a model for an object using the PDO with no ORM in between. We can debate about why I'm not using an ORM later.

I have a few static methods, such as getById() and getByName() that instantiate and return a model object if one exists in the database.

My question: what should I return, to be "morally correct", if that row doesn't exist in the database? Since this is new code on a project without any good guidelines on how to proceed here, I could return (and check for later) false or null...or theoretically something else. What I'd rather not do is have is_object() checks in my code where I could just be using ===.

I already throw an exception if my prepared SELECT statement execute() returns false. I suppose I could throw an exception as well if no object was found, but I don't know of an ORM that actually does that.

Thanks in advance, and let any holy war that may commence do so!

Comment: Why not an exception?

Comment: It really depends on the expectations of the method. Is it an *exceptional* case to not return an entry? Is the code that is calling the method going to be 'surprised' if one isn't found? My guess is no. You should probably be returning null. To me, throwing an exception would mean "oh no! something went wrong!" whereas null would mean, "nothing was found." The exception (*terrible pun*) would be if null is a valid entity to return. (But for a record--not a column--that shouldn't be the case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would return null, it meets all of your criteria.

It is falsey so a simple if is a test to see if the asset was retrieved would work

```
if ($user)
```

Testing for '=== null' clearly indicates the meaning of the test.

```
if ($user === null)
```

And null in my opinion is more semantically correct than false.  You got a null result as oppossed to a false result from your call.